# Run Selenium On Qt Desktop Application

Tags: c++, qt, selenium, automation, header-files

I have a qt desktop application and i am required to use selenium for developing automated tests on it.

I found this web driver option: https://github.com/cisco-open-source/qtwebdriver

I cloned, build and installed the driver according to this wiki:

https://github.com/cisco-open-source/qtwebdriver/wiki/Build-And-Run

and also checked the web driver running on port 9517 according to this wiki.

Now i want to bind the web driver to my project.

I followed this wiki:

https://github.com/cisco-open-source/qtwebdriver/wiki/Use-QtWebDriver-to-run-your-application

in the second section, Option 1: WebDriver attaches to the running application.

when i am adding the "Headers.h" file, i get the error:

```
"base/at_exit.h": No such file or directory
```

i guess its because i didnt do the parent step as needed ("Add the QtWebDriver headers and libraries in the application build environment")

im not sure i added the webdriver project as needed.

to add the librarys i choosed "Add Library" -> "External Library" in the wizard, and choosed all the so files from the webdriver project.

then i also added all the existing h files by choosing "add existing files" in the Headers folder of my project.

is it the right way to add the library to my project?

what am i missing?

Comment: I dont see selenium supports desktop application unless it open in browser

Comment: this webdriver opens the application in a browser

Comment: I believe the build actually builds the libraries you need... so add from build directory, or whatever directory holds all the "#include" files in Headers.h

Comment: btw, as I understand it (and I've never worked with QT before) this does not open the application in the browser... you are either putting the qtwebdriver  into your application (option1) so that your qt selenium app can hook into it, or you are putting your application into your qt selenium application(option2).  If your application can already be launched in a browser, there is no need for any of this, as standard Selenium can already automate the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `include_directories` of the folder contains "base" folder to the cmakelists file.