# Windows Automation API -- WebDriver => what is the equivalent possibility to automate 3rd party Qt DESKTOP applications / QQuick GUI?

Tags: python, shell, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, qt6

My intention is to realise a robust User interaction emulation on a 3rd party application that has been developed using QT 6.3. I have no access to the code, thus any usage of a test automation tool wouldn't work.
With "robust" I mean that I would like to "code" the selection of the respective GUI elements in contrary to RPA solutions using pixel based navigation or image recognition.

In legacy Windows applications automation is possible using the automation API.
In web applications automation can be realised using the WebDriver (W3C) interface.

What is the equivalent regarding QT applications?

The commercial tools Squish and Ranorex are no alternatives due to the considerable licence costs and the overhead (I don't need testing functionality at all).

In this post [Run Selenium On Qt Desktop Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58066135/run-selenium-on-qt-desktop-application/75536842#75536842) a user describes an attempt to use Qt **Desktop** application with Selenium framework using Cisco's qtWebDriver.

Did someone succeed the combination of Selenium and a Desktop app and could outline how this works?
I invested quite some time to play around and learn Selenium and qtWebDriver, but still I cannot see how a "Desktop App" could be connected to interact with Selenium.

Moreover, could someone confirm or contradict that qtWebDriver no longer works with QML GUI as of version > 6.x due to architectural changes.
The Qt WebKit/ QWebView API has been replaced by the Qt WebEngine/ QWebEngineView.

Many thanks.

Maybe [QAccessible](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/accessible-qtquick.html) could be a possibility, but reading the documentation they only explain how to set the accessibility properties, but I didn't understand how to fetch the accessibility metadata and how to code interaction.

I tried out all existing UI spy tools.
Of those, only Ranorex Spy and Squish Spy can identify the UI element hierarchy.

But even knowing the UI hierarchy neither FlaUI, nor Powershell, nor WindowsDriver etc have any support for Qt / QML classes.

Answer (score 0):

My current project uses cisco webdriver for test automation.It works fine. However, our application is written for Linux. QT 5.15. The webdriver was implemented in the project before I came to this position, so i wouldn't use it now as the cisco webdirver project looks dead.
I also tried funq: https://github.com/parkouss/funq. But unfortunately in my application it did not see the whole structure.
I once automated applications on Windows through autoit. I don't know if it works with qt apps.
You may also check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_GUI_testing_tools

Globally, I have seen three approaches to automating desktop applications:

1. click on the coordinates with checking the screenshots of the result (very flacky)
2. using libraries to access the internals of the application and interact through it. (basically i've found only one option here - squish)
3. CV (with it, you can automate a lot of things without access to the internals of the program. but writing tests is quite labor intensive)

Comment: Thank you @Ivan for your feedback.
Regarding automation, your 3rd option "CV", what do you mean by it? Are you talking about OpenCV image recognition based automation?

Comment: Yes, computer vision